# Rolling over a series by avoiding NaNs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

How to perform rolling computation by avoiding `NaN` values in my case ?

My series:

```
2019-05-01    0.1
2019-05-02    0.2
2019-05-03    NaN
2019-05-04    NaN
2019-05-05    NaN
2019-05-06    0.1
2019-05-07    0.5
2019-05-08    NaN
2019-05-09    0.1
2019-05-10    0.2
2019-05-11    NaN
2019-05-12    NaN
2019-05-13    0.3
```

I need to compute the mean of period 2 of this series in a way that my output is:

```
2019-05-01     NaN
2019-05-02    0.15
2019-05-03     NaN
2019-05-04     NaN
2019-05-05     NaN
2019-05-06    0.15
2019-05-07    0.30
2019-05-08     NaN
2019-05-09    0.30
2019-05-10    0.15
2019-05-11     NaN
2019-05-12     NaN
2019-05-13    0.25
```

Using `rolling`, if you do not have 2 subsequent non-`NaN` values, the mean will return NaN so it doesn't work (below the result with dropping NaNs):

```
2019-05-01     NaN
2019-05-02    0.15
2019-05-03     NaN
2019-05-04     NaN
2019-05-05     NaN
2019-05-06     NaN
2019-05-07    0.30
2019-05-08     NaN
2019-05-09     NaN
2019-05-10    0.15
2019-05-11     NaN
2019-05-12     NaN
2019-05-13     NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `dropna` first then `rolling` `reindex` back

```
s.dropna().rolling(2).mean().reindex(s.index)
Out[796]: 
2019-05-01     NaN
2019-05-02    0.15
2019-05-03     NaN
2019-05-04     NaN
2019-05-05     NaN
2019-05-06    0.15
2019-05-07    0.30
2019-05-08     NaN
2019-05-09    0.30
2019-05-10    0.15
2019-05-11     NaN
2019-05-12     NaN
2019-05-13    0.25
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can impute your data using the last presented value:

```
temp = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Then calculate the rolling mean:

```
temp = temp.rolling(2).mean()
```

and finally replace NaNs:

```
temp.loc[np.isnan(df)] = np.nan
```